# Routing with command controller and sub controllers without using areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I create a routing structure for a project management application where there are discrete controllers for all the relevant pieces such as TaskController, DocumentController etc and an Over arching controller. I would essentially like a structure like:

http://server/Project/123/Task
http://server/Project/123/Document

I am using mvc1 so I have no access to areas etc. The project section will have a separate master page for project controllers such as task, document etc with a dfferent menu navigaton.  I have tried three routes together n Global.asax like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Task",
            "Project/{id}/Task/{action}",
            new { controller = "Task", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Message",
            "Project/{id}/Message/{action}",
            new { controller = "Message", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Document",
            "Project/{id}/Document/{action}",
            new { controller = "Document", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: Are there any other routes defined that could be conflicting or are these the only three routes?

Comment: Which controller and action do you get when you call http://server/Project/123/Document?

Comment: Malcolm you get DocumentController with Action Index(int projectid)

Answer (score 0):

Use the route debugger to see what is going wrong http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx